# UK 6 months visa about to expire

Tags: visas, uk

I have a UK tourist visa for 6 months. Am currently in the UK and my visa is about to expire.I have decided to stay in the UK for at least year. Can i renew my visa before it expires while in UK?

Answer (score 2):

No, you may not extend your tourist Visa for any period longer than 6 months.  The maximum allowed is 6 months.  If your original Visa was shorter than 6 months, then you could apply for an extension up to 6 months from your date of arrival.  But in your case, your six months are almost over and your Visa was for 6 months.

[See here](https://www.gov.uk/general-visit-visa/extend-your-visa) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

UK Tourist Visas are a maximum of 6 months stay within the country. You will have to exit the country and apply for a new visa or if you visa hasn't expired then you can re-enter the country. Although they will be pretty suspicious if you stay for the full 6 months then re-enter.